# storing values from multiple jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My application needs to display different sets of information in different jtable, for example, if the application has Group 1 result,Group 2 result and  Group 3 result then, I need to display each group in a separate tab in separate using separate jtable for each group. When the user press a button on tool bar, i need to validate all the jtable and ensure they are not empty. The issue what i am facing is - since the number of jtable created will be dynamic(based on the number of groups at run time), can some one suggest me a design approach which help me to maintain the list of jtables created and iterate through the jtable. Any suggestions or reference example will be of great help!

Sample Code: -

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{                         
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    // here i need to print the JTable Name                                 
}     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is **very** broad, perhaps too broad to answer adequately, but it appears that you will need a `java.util.List<T>` of *something* (often implemented as an `ArrayList<T>`). That may be a `List<JTable>`, or a `List<ClassThatHoldsATable>` or perhaps `List<ModelsForATable>`. This way you can add or remove items from the list as needed, iterate through the list doing whatever validation is needed,... etc.

Edit: You've edited your question and now state pretty much the same thing. Given this edit, I'm not really sure where you're stuck.

---

**Edit**
Based on your updated question and code:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{                         
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    // here i need to print the JTable Name                                 
}     
});
```

Issues:

- I usually avoid mouseClicked since it can be easy for it to not respond to the user if the click, move the mouse slightly and then release. I usually use the mousePressed method.
- What do you mean by "JTable Name"? If you mean the variable name, then don't go that route since variable names aren't all that helpful or useful. If you mean the JTable object reference, which is much more important than a variable name, well, then you've got it:

e.g.,

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapater() {

    @Override // never forget this guy
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        // you've got your JTable reference right here!
        JTable selectedTable = (JTable) e.getSource();

        // now what you do with it will depend on your needs and your code
    }
});
```

If you absolutely need to associate an object with a String, then consider using a `Map<JTable, String>` such as a HashMap.

Comment: Thank you! let me try this approach now!

Comment: your approach helped me! Thank you. However, i might need your help again. In my application(Consider the example in my question), when the user performs a mouse click operation on any one of these jtable, i need to store that jtable name, is it possible to retrieve/identify the jtable?

Comment: yeah, i tried this. I have 2 JTables, and onClick, i print this information - e.getSource().toString(); However, both the jTable print the same information "javax.swing.JTable[,0,0,450x80,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=251658568,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,autoCreateColumnsFromModel=true,autoResizeMode=AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS,cellSelectionEnabled=false,editingColumn= ..." i am unable to differentiate the jTable. Your suggestions on how to identify the table will be really helpful.... thanks....

Comment: @Jagan: toString() can help with debugging, but as in most things, the devil exists in the details. If you need more specific help, then you first, please tell us more of the details and show us your pertinent code, preferably as a [minimal example program or MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jagan: Also, please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27879007/edit). Again, we'd best be able to help you if you create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){                         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
  String text = e.getSource().toString();
// here i need to print the JTable Name                                 }                                                                     });

Comment: I apologise for the incorrect update! i am new to this and i will correct my mistakes

Comment: i have updated the code in the original post. Can you please guide me/